# Supporting long unicode filepaths with System.Data.SQLite

Tags: sqlite, unicode, system.data.sqlite

I'm developing an application that needs to be able to create & manipulate SQLite databases in user-defined paths. I'm running into a problem I don't really understand. I'm testing my stuff against some really gross sample data with huge unwieldy unicode paths, for most of them there isn't a problem, but for one there is.

An example of a working connection string is:

```
Data Source="c:\test6\意外な高価で売れるかも？　出品は手順を覚えれば後はかんたん！\11オークションストアの出品は対象外とさせていただきます。\test.db";Version=3;
```

While one that fails is

```
Data Source="c:\test6\意外な高価で売れるかも？　出品は手順を覚えれば後はかんたん！\22今やPCライフに欠かせないのがセキュリティソフト。そのため、現在何種類も発売されているが、それぞれ似\test.db";Version=3;
```

I'm using System.Data.SQLite v1.0.66.0 due to reasons outside of my control, but I quickly tested with the latest, v1.0.77.0 and had the same problems.

Both when attempting to newly create the test.db file or if I manually put one there and it's attempting to open, SQLiteConnection.Open throws an exception saying only "Unable to open the database file", with the stack trace showing that it's actually System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open that is throwing.

Is there any way I can get System.Data.SQLite to play nicely with these paths? A workaround could be to create and manipulate my databases in a temporary location and then just move them to the actual locations for storage, since I can create and manipulate files normally otherwise. That's kind of a last resort though.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing you are on a Japanese-locale machine where the default system encoding (ANSI code page) is cp932 Japanese (≈Shift-JIS).

The second path contains:

```
ソ
```

which encodes to the byte sequence:

```
0x83 0x5C
```

Shift-JIS is a multibyte encoding that has the unfortunate property of sometimes re-using ASCII code units in the trail byte. In this case it has used byte 0x5C which corresponds to the backslash `\`. (Though this typically displays as a yen sign in Japanese fonts, for historical reasons.)

So if this pathname is passed into a byte-based API, it will get encoded in the ANSI code page, and you won't be able to tell the difference between a backslash meant as a directory separator and one that is a side-effect of multi-byte encoding. Consequently any path with one of the following characters in will fail when accessed with a byte-based IO method:

```
―ソЫⅨ噂浬欺圭構蚕十申曾箪貼能表暴予禄兔喀媾彌拿杤歃畚秉綵臀藹觸軆鐔饅鷭偆砡纊犾
```

(Also any pathname that contains a Unicode character not present in cp932 will naturally fail.)

It would appear that behind the scenes SQLite is using a byte-based IO method to open the filename it is given. This is unfortunate, but extremely common in cross-platform code, because the POSIX C standard library is defined to use byte-based filenames for operations like file `open()`.

Consequently using the C stdlib functions it is impossible to reliably access files with non-ASCII names. This sad situation inherits into all sorts of cross-platform libraries and languages written using the stdlib; only tools written with specific support for Win32 Unicode filenames (eg Python) can reliably access all files under Windows.

Your options, then, are:

1. avoid using non-ASCII characters in the path name for your db, as per the move/rename suggestion;
2. continue to rely on the system locale being Japanese (ANSI code page=932), and just rename files to avoid any of the characters listed above;
3. get the short (8.3) filename of the file in question and use that instead of the real one—something like `c:\test6\85D0~1\22PC~1\test.db`. You can use `dir /x` to see the short-filenames. They are always pure ASCII, avoiding the encoding problem;
4. add some code to get the short filename from the real one, using GetShortPathName. This is a Win32 API so you need a little [help](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getshortpathname) to call it from .NET. Note also short filenames will still fail if run on a machine with the short filename generation feature disabled;
5. persuade SQLite to add support for Windows Unicode filenames;
6. persuade Microsoft to fix this problem once and for all by making the default encoding for byte interfaces UTF-8, like it is on all other modern operating systems.